# Reading large text file with double pipe delimiters

Tags: r, text, import, delimiter

Using R, I am trying to read in a large (1.3 g) text file with || double pipe delimiters. Specifically, it looks like this:

```
||Header1||,||header2||,||Header3||
||0.001||,||0.002||,||0.003||
```

I have had success in terms of speed with the fread function described [here](http://davetang.org/muse/2013/09/03/handling-big-data-in-r/). However, the function doesn't allow delimiters with more than 1 character. So when i set sep ="auto", I get cells with the right values, but they have "||" on both sides.

I would do a find and replace in a text editor to change "||" to ",", but its too large to be done in a reasonable amount of time.

Your help is a life saver. Thank you!

Comment: I've edited my answer.  Hope that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those don't look to be delimiters, but maybe they are and I just don't know it.  Either way, instead of changing `||` to `,` it looks like they can simply be removed and then the resulting vector can then be put into a data frame with `read.csv`.

In the code for `g` below, replace `textConnection(txt)` with your file name.

```
txt <- "||Header1||,||header2||,||Header3||
||0.001||,||0.002||,||0.003||"
g <- gsub("||", "", readLines(textConnection(txt)), fixed=TRUE)
read.csv(text = g)
#   Header1 header2 Header3
# 1   0.001   0.002   0.003
```